# how to make two rows horizontal collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I want to make two rows collection view in horizontal like below

[image]

I am new in iOS development, and some tutorials just give example how to make certain number of columns of collection view vertically, but i need to limit the number of rows of the collection view

I have tried to make the number of section to be two but still, the number of row still one

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!


    let imageArray = [UIImage(named: "image1"),UIImage(named: "image2"),UIImage(named: "image3"),UIImage(named: "image4"),UIImage(named: "image5"),UIImage(named: "image6"),UIImage(named: "image8"),UIImage(named: "image9")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
        cell.avatarView.image = imageArray[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: A collection view can be horizontal or vertical. Yours is horizontal. So it works _exactly_ like the two-column vertical collection views you've read about. Just substitute "width" for "height" in the discussion of how to make the cells be the right size, and you're all set. It's trivial. No need for sections or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

[Please update the section inset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGOaE.png)

```swift
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCell
    cell.avatarView.image = imageArray[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

```swift
 public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let padding: CGFloat =  60
        let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.height - padding

        return CGSize(width: 100, height: collectionViewSize/2)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below in your code

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.height/2, height: collectionView.frame.height/2)

    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
```